# query mysql database with time

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to query a database in such a manner where all rows which comes in the given time are fetched.
My DB table has a Date column which holds data like this

```
2012-04-23 08:39:10
2012-04-23 08:41:37
2012-04-23 13:49:56
```

i want to get all rows that contain the time like 5 min before. Actually what i am trying here is to show all users that were online 5 min before. These dates and times are created with their last activity.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: i was trying this `Date` > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '5' MINUTE))
but obviously it didn't worked...:(

Comment: what was the error or problem when you try this, because nearly all all solutions provided here even yours will gave same result, all of them are correct. `SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '5' MINUTE)` ,  `DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`, `subtime(now(),'00:05:00')`

Comment: @Prashank: that SQL will give you all the records in the table that fall between now and 5 minutes ago.  It sounds like what you wanting are only the records *from* 5 minutes ago.  For that you will need to use an `=` in your SQL or try using `BETWEEN`.

Comment: It didn't gave any error it just didn't filtered the result which come within 5 min. It just gave all records of the table

Comment: nah i need all rows which comes within 5 min. that part is okay

Comment: And did you try any of suggestions? What is the result?

Comment: I don't know what was the reason but when i tried my own code it worked this time...???

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you

```
select * from tablename where ((datecol > subtime(now(),'00:05:00')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table> 
WHERE 
  <date column> 
    BETWEEN 
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) 
    AND 
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `TABLE_NAME`
WHERE `DATECOLUMN` > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```